# How to update the rails datetime field to match with user timezone?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I did like following model method. It's working fine for me. But I don't know whether it's working in all conditions.

Server store all the time records as UTC format. So here I get the current user formatted offset, Based on that I update the endtime.

```
    def update_job
     off = Time.now.formatted_offset
     off_split = off.gsub(off.first, '').split(':')
     if off.first == '+'
      off_dat = self.enddate = self.enddate - off_split.first.to_i.hours
      off_dat = self.enddate = self.enddate - off_split.last.to_i.minutes if off_split.length == 2
     elsif off.first == '-'
      off_dat = self.enddate = self.enddate + off_split.first.to_i.hours
      off_dat = self.enddate = self.enddate + off_split.last.to_i.minutes if off_split.length == 2
     end
     self.update_attributes(enddate: off_dat)
    end
```

can I use above code?

Comment: you can change the timezone according to this  for application, (in this time will be stored in UTC , but while fetching it you will get time zone that you have set in config )http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html, you do not need to store it in UTC , you can store it in any zone format , active record will sense it and will store it in UTC

Answer (score 0):

you can change the timezone for application, (in this time will be stored in UTC , but while fetching it you will get time  in the zone that you have set in config)

```
api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html
```

you do not need to store time in UTC , you can store it in any zone format , active record will sense it and will store it in UTC

If you have case where every user can have different time zone and they need to see data in their time zone, Then you need to store user time zone in users table Then in application controller you can set it dynamically

```
#callback

def set_user_time_zone
  if current_user
      Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
  else
    Time.zone = config.time_zone
  end
end
```